# Fetching data of kafka queue within a certain defined time range

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am trying to extract message of kafka queue based on certain time ranges, say between `Oct 2, 1 PM and Oct 2, 3 PM`. How can I explicitly define this time range and just pull data off these time ranges.

```
bootstrap_servers = ['servername.com']
topicName = 'sales_topic'
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topicName, group_id='sales', bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers, auto_offset_reset='earliest', consumer_timeout_ms=20000)
```

I read about `offsets_for_times` but I am not sure how to use that. Any help around this would be appreciated.

Comment: So, you read about the method, but have you tried it? What specific errors are you getting with it?

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for checking on this. It expected a dict but when I passed a dict to KafkaConsumer method it did not recognise it so wondering where am I going wrong. Given below is the error

`KafkaConfigurationError: KafkaConfigurationError: Unrecognized configs: {'offsets_for_times'}`

Comment: It's not a config option. It is a consumer instance method that returns values, which you then give to `consumer.seek()` method